# dynamic routing with php front controller

Tags: php, front-controller

I'm trying to fetch control name from URL and match it with correct controller dynamically in index.php.

My app root : /localhost/app/index.php

So basically when i typed  /localhost/app/index.php/home, trying to inlude home_controller.php.
Here is code;

```
 $parts = array_slice(explode('/',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]),3);
 if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/controllers/".$parts[0].'_controller.php'))
 {
    include dirname(__FILE__)."/controllers/".$parts[0].'_controller.php';
 }
```

It works fine if the app root depth is 3. It's broken when i changed app directory like
localhost/first/second/app/index.php/home

Because it's explode by 3, $parts[0] is no longer "home"
The question is how can i detect controller part in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used $_SERVER paht_info variable to calculate, controller part..

```
  $segments = array_slice(explode("/", $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] ),1);
```

Zero index of $segment array is the controller part and the other parts is the function.
Btw you need to check array boundries and whether path_info is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

/localhost/app/index.php/home
localhost/first/second/app/index.php/home
sounds like its making your string the $parts[0] piece look like app/index.php/home which would be an invalid path. The only way to handle this is either explode that string with / as your delimiter or using the last one in the array as the location to compare or run through each. The concept of MVC though is the URL is always structured similar part one, home in this case required to determin controller, 2+ are usually used in refrence to parameters to a function from the controller

Comment: thank you. I'm not using CI. After explode with "/" still I'll have localhost,first,second,app,index.php,home.. I dont want to loop in this array to find correct controller.As you can see, it's not efficient.. Also what happens if run through backward, if the url is localhost/first/second/app/index.php/home/settings? I just want to call home controller's settings function. @chris

Comment: Im only thinking some crazy things lol. None of which are going to work well for what sounds like might be your end game.